# How do I use librosa in Xcode for audio feature extraction?

Tags: python, xcode, librosa

I would like to use some feature extraction techniques in Xcode using Swift. How can I import Python, librosa or any such thing in Xcode? What exactly I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [python framework](https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit) for swift 5, that can be used to call python code. The sample code from the authors GitHub suggests:

```
import PythonKit
let sys = try Python.import("sys")
print("Python \(sys.version_info.major).\(sys.version_info.minor)")
print("Python Version: \(sys.version)")
print("Python Encoding: \(sys.getdefaultencoding().upper())")
```

You can use it to load librosa library and perform audio file manipulations and feature extractions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I have already tried using this PythonKit and there are several errors that I get in my Xcode. ex. Python_Library environment variable is not set , Ambigious python library and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I partially ported it to Swift. It's early version but you can try use it.

please try find RosaKit in GitHub

Comment: Hi Dmytro! Please describe the solution you're suggesting and provide a link to the GitHub. "try to find" would be a useful comment but not a great answer :)

Comment: I found this github link related to RosaKit over 15 days ago.

Comment: There is link to my repo:https://github.com/dhrebeniuk/RosaKit

Comment: @DmytroHrebeniuk, Can you please tell me how can I use RosaKit to extract mfcc features?

Comment: @Rocky, thanks for question. Currently not implemented. I add this functionality if needed in update.

Comment: @DmytroHrebeniuk, I'll really appreciate it if you can add this functionality or shed some light on how it can be achieved with the existing functionalities.